# Using AJAX to dynamically draw circles with Google Maps

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I am playing around with some geographical data, using the Google Maps API to generate circles on a map. Easy. The data is coming from a MySQL database and I am using PHP to print this into the script on loading. The structure of the JavaScript object looks like this:

```
var circles = { 
    1 : { center : new google.maps.LatLng(55,-1), size: 1000},
    2 : { center : new google.maps.LatLng(56,-2), size: 2000}
};
```

**Goal**

The circles are not arbitrary and the locations they represent have associated characteristics which I would like to filter on. Assume a drop down box allows you to select the size range of the circles displayed on the map. When changed, the map will reload the circles based on this selection.

I have created a PHP script which generates the data and have tried to use AJAX (jQuery) to assign the response to the circles variable, as shown below. When I have cracked it the idea is that the script will generate different data based on the drop down selection.

```
var circles = {};
var circles = $.ajax({
    url: "data.php",
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

The text that the PHP (data.php) script generates is this:

> 1 : { center : new google.maps.LatLng(55,-1), size: 1000},2 : { center : new google.maps.LatLng(56,-2), size: 2000}

However, this does not work. I may be missing a step or be on the wrong track but any guidance would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @davidkonrad, I didn't manage to make his answer work. The problem was with transferring the `new google.maps.LatLng(55,-1)` object as JSON.

My solution has been to split the latitude and longitude variables in the JSON generated by the PHP script.

JSON Structure:

```
{"1" : { "lat" : 55, "lng" : -1, "size": 10000}}
```

Then in the options or each circle I set the center:

```
center : new google.maps.LatLng(circle.lat,circle.lng)
```